# Edit head section thorough body

Tags: javascript, tags, meta, head

I want to add this meta tag in the head sction:

```
<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="somerandometext2"/>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the head section, and I want to do it through the body section.

Is that possible?

Comment: `document.head.appendChild`

Comment: The point of that tag is to verify that you can edit the `<head>`.  If you can't edit it, you can't verify.

Comment: Any js you did this with would be called after the head was loaded so you could try something like document.head (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head) but it's unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

No.

After the HTML has been parsed into a DOM, you can use JavaScript in the browser to manipulate the DOM to add a new meta *element*.

```
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute("name", "p:domain_verify");
meta.setAttribute("content", "somerandometext2");
document.head.appendChild(meta);
```

… but that won't touch the HTML and so won't touch the tags.

This *might* be enough to achieve your goal, but the odds are that any software which cares about meta tags isn't going to execute JavaScript in the body before looking for them.